# SQL group by without group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Apologies for the stupid title of the question, but wasn't able to come up with anything more descriptive.

I have the following data in my table:

```
Name; Day ; Mood
----------------
Bob; Fri; Sad
Bob; Thu; Sad
Bob; Wed; Happy
Bob; Tue; Happy
Bob; Mon; Sad
```

Assume it's Saturday. You know Bob is Sad (you grouped by Name, and you maxed over the Day ). However, you would like to know since when Bob is Sad.

The answer is since Thursday. I would like to write an SQL query that tells me that. Problem is with Monday, since by writing the query naively, one could conclude that Bob is Sad since Mon. This, however, would be wrong, because of the Happy Mood on Tue and Wed.

Any help very much appreciated (can be Oracle specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the adjacent groups using a trick with `row_number()`.  Then you can get the length of the last one by using aggregation:

```
select max(date) as date, mood
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by mood order by date)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp, mood
order by max(date) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Oracle 12 supports the final clause `fetch first 1 row only`.  In earlier versions, you can do the same thing with a subquery and `where rownum = 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It will take me some time to understand what exactly is going on in this query, though. In the meantime, however, I'm getting "missing right parenthesis" error. I tried to fix, but I failed. Could you please help?

Comment: @SimonRighley . . . It will help if you just focus on the subquery, look at the two row number values separately and then see what the difference does.